# Фактор чи чинник?

Tags: різниця-між-словами

На сайті "Онлайнкоректор":
  Не зловживайте запозиченою лексикою, замініть іменник фактор на власне український: чинник.

Форум "Словник.нет":
   Фактор не русизм, а латинізм. Збігається з чинником у першому значенні. Власне, саме в цьому значенні варто надавати перевагу питомому слову. Хоч це не значить, що іншомовного синоніма треба уникати завжди. Для врізноманітнення мовлення деколи можна використати й латинізм. Інша річ, коли вживають тільки фактор, зовсім забуваючи чинника.

То яке з цих слів варто використовувати?

Comment: будь ласка, додавайте гіперпосилання. ви знаєте, як це робити?

Answer (score 3):

У Словнику української мови в 11 томах зазначено:

> **[ФАКТОР](http://sum.in.ua/s/faktor)**
>   **1.** Умова, рушійна сила будь-якого процесу, явища; чинник. **2.** У дореволюційній Росії — керівник технічної частини друкарні, що
>   здійснював безпосередній зв'язок між друкарнею та замовником.**3.**
>   Посередник, дрібний комісіонер, маклер. **4.** мат. Кожне з перемножуваних
>   чисел; співмножник.
>
> **[ЧИННИК](http://sum.in.ua/s/chynnyk)** Умова, рушійна сила, причина будь-якого процесу, що визначає його характер або одну з основних рис; фактор.

*[Словник синонімів](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA)*

> **ЧИ́ННИК** (умова, рушійна сила, причина якогось процесу, що визначає його характер), ФА́КТОР, АГЕ́НТ. - *На літературу звертаю лиш остільки
>   увагу, оскільки вона мала вплив на політику, виступала як свідомий
>   чинник громадського життя* (І. Франко); *Добрива є одним з вирішальних
>   факторів боротьби за врожай* (з журналу).

Краще вживати слово **"чинник"** в значені умова, причин процесу, слово **"фактор"** має більш широке значення, тому його краще використовувати в 2,3,4 варіантах (наведених вище в визначенні даного слова).

Зокремо в [Російсько-українських словниках](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on) наведено багато прикладів використання слова ***"фактор"***.

Comment: Може якраз і варто обмежувати? Перше значення залишити для чинник, а фактор вживати лише в 2, 3, 4? Це лише моя особиста думка, я не претендую на якусь об'єктивність.

Comment: @Yola мені краще відредаґувати відповідь? А саме: "Краще вживати слово "чинник" в значені умова, причин процесу, слово "фактор" має більш широке значення, тому його краще використовувати в 2,3,4 варіантах. "

Comment: Я б відредагував, але це залежить від вашої особистої думки. Якщо таким чином розділяти значення між словами, то легше стає розуміти мову. Я цей підхід вперше зустрів у Антоненко-Давидовича і він мені дуже подобається.

Comment: @Yola дякую за пораду. Саме так і відредаґую відповідь.